# How to make a separate divs and result for every added friend in react?

Tags: reactjs

In this react code when 2 more friends are added then the debt remains the instead of different sections i think this is due to same SplitColumn and the answer of the finalSplit in the code pls review it by trying in your devices . i am a new learner so pls fix and explain how  to do it . i have tried finding through chatgpt and stuff but aint got nothing that can fix this issue

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';

const body = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.body);
body.render(<App />);

function App(){
  let [col,setCol] = useState('close')
  function handleAddFrndBtn(){
    col === 'close'?setCol('open'):setCol('close');
  }
  let [inputValue,setInputValue] = useState('')
  function frnd_name_input(e){
    setInputValue(e.target.value)
  }
  let [friends,setFriends] = useState([])
  function handleAddBtn(){
    const newFriend = inputValue.trim();
    if (newFriend !== '') {
      setFriends([...friends, newFriend]);
      setInputValue('');
      setCol('close')
    }
  }
  let [splitCol,setSplitCol] = useState('close')
  let [username,SetUsername] = useState('')
  function handleFrndSelect(index){
    splitCol === 'close'?setSplitCol('open'):setSplitCol('close');
    SetUsername(friends[index])
  }
  let [bill,setBill] = useState(0)
  function billing(e){
    setBill(Number(e.target.value))
  }
  let [bill_you,setBillYou] = useState(0)
  function billByYou(e){
    setBillYou(Number(e.target.value))
  }
  let [bill_frnd,setBillFrnd] = useState(0)
  function billByFrnd(e){
    setBillFrnd(Number(bill - bill_you))
    e.target.value = bill_frnd
  }
  let [finalSplit,setFinalSplit] = useState(``)
  function calc(){
    bill_you > bill_frnd ? setFinalSplit(`Your Friend Owes You ${(bill/2)-bill_frnd}`):setFinalSplit(`Your Owe ${(bill/2)-bill_you} To Your Friend`)
  }
  return <div className='root'>
    <Friends add_frnd = {handleAddFrndBtn} columnStatus = {col}
    input_name={frnd_name_input} add_btn={handleAddBtn} frnds={friends} frnd_select={handleFrndSelect} finalSplit={finalSplit}/>
    <SplitColumn splitColumnStatus={splitCol} user={username} billing={billing} billByYou={billByYou} billByFrnd={billByFrnd} bill_frnd={bill_frnd}
    calc={calc}/>
  </div>
}
function Friends({add_frnd,columnStatus,input_name,add_btn,frnds,frnd_select,finalSplit}){
  return <div className='friends_list'>
    <button id="add_frnds" onClick={add_frnd}>Add Friend</button>
    <div className={`add_column_${columnStatus}`}>
      <input type='text' placeholder='Name Of Friend' onChange={input_name}></input>
      <div className='btns'>
        <button id="add" onClick={add_btn}>ADD</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    {frnds.map((frnd,index)=>{
      return <div className='frnd' key={index} onClick={() => frnd_select(index)}>
        <img src='user.png' alt='user'></img>
        <span>{frnd}</span>
        <span>Debt : {finalSplit}</span>
      </div>
    })}
  </div>
}
function SplitColumn({splitColumnStatus,user,billing,billByYou,billByFrnd,calc}){
  return <div className={`SplitColumn${splitColumnStatus}`}>
    <span>For {user}</span>
    <input type='number' min={0} className='bill' placeholder='Total Bill Amount' onChange={billing}></input>
    <input type='number' min={0} className='bill_you' placeholder='Total Amount Paid By You' onChange={billByYou}></input>
    <input type='number' min={0} className='bill_frnd' placeholder="Total Amount Paid By Your Friend" onClick={billByFrnd}></input>
    <button onClick={calc}>CALCULATE</button>
  </div>
}
```